# Too many arguments Q

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to write a measure that will allow me to filter on statuscode and Datesbetween.  With the filter, plus the two conditions, I have too many arguments for the FILTER function.  What syntax can I use to get the desired result?

```
Won-Existing = 
SUMX (
    FILTER ( _enquiries,
        _enquiries[_GUID] = _2018_Budget[_GUID] &&
        _enquiries[statuscode] = 866120005 &&
        DATESBETWEEN(_enquiries[Date Contract Awarded],DATE(2018,8,1),DATE(2018,8,31) 
    ),
    _enquiries[Amount (Enq)]
))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like some parentheses mismatching to me. Try this:

```
Won-Existing = 
SUMX (
    FILTER ( _enquiries,
        _enquiries[_GUID] = _2018_Budget[_GUID] &&
        _enquiries[statuscode] = 866120005 &&
        DATESBETWEEN(_enquiries[Date Contract Awarded], DATE(2018,8,1), DATE(2018,8,31)) 
    ),
    _enquiries[Amount (Enq)]
)
```

Comment: Thanks, Alexis, but I keep getting the same error message...

A date column containing duplicate dates was specified in the call to function 'DATESBETWEEN'. This is not supported. Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have a calendar table? If yes, then you should use that date column in the `DATESBETWEEN` function. If no, you probably need one.